# Issue with "Start a List Workflow" - Workflow Interop

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, impersonation, app-step, interop-bridge

I created a test workflow to test the App Step in 2013 WF and the Impersonation Step in 2010 WF. See below.

2013 Workflow using App Step:

[image: 2013 Workflow]

2010 Workflow using Impersonation Step:

[image]

I know what most of you are thinking..."its not working because the "Start a List" action isn't included in the App Step. Well, when I tried to add it there, there wasn't an option to add that action. I could only do it outside of the app step. So that's why I added the Impersonation Step in the 2010 WF, to make sure that it had the permissions it needed.

When the workflow starts, I get this error:

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Forbidden to https://{site}/sites/hhc/IT/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.InteropService.Current/EnableEvents(listId='987ca198-260a-42d6-b178-3e0c6a79a17a',itemGuid='b82bf850-9b82-412d-9139-408bc8170450') Correlation Id: 483143e6-812b-9c5d-ab7a-79a822bbc1db Instance Id: 71d42041-4764-4045-9bd1-f6d273aba2c5
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, or how I can call a 2010 WF in 2013? I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

In 2013, you can use the "Start a List workflow" to start a 2010 workflow:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/workflow-actions-quick-reference-sharepoint-workflow-platform#workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2013

If you can't add the Start a List Workflow in the App step, you should be able to using the Impersonation just like you normally would in 2010, but outside the app step. The impersonation step will pick up the rights to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have the Start a List workflow outside of the app step and the 2010 has the Impersonation Step, and its giving me that error. I didn't think you could do an impersonation step in 2013?

Comment: found that it may be a hotfix: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2015/12/08/december-2015-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-is-available-for-download/ check this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0cdc4a08-b327-460c-9a9c-b9bf18ce1abd/large-list-unable-to-use-workflow-interop?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: Does this apply for SharePoint Online?

Comment: whats your threshold's set at? Maybe raise them and try it again.